# how to make my fetch space your calls?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

I am making a movie search engine to an API. I have a Fetch that makes calls to the api with each search for a title, which has limited the requests to 6 per second. When I try to search for a movie with more than one result I get a warning saying that I have exceeded the number of requests per second. I would like to know how to make my Fetch make the calls intermittently, two per second, for example. That is to say, that it doses its calls in time.

Comment: Estás en stackoverflow en español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta o elimínala y colócala en https://stackoverflow.com/